# Access-Control-Allow-Origin alwasy set to * in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, access-control

I am setting CORS using the following configurations, in spring boot, but the browser shows as if I am using * not the specified URL !

```
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The easier way support by spring boot is sets @CrossOrigin annotation on the controller.

Example:

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")

2. Of if you use spring security:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}
```

And many ways to set cors, follow this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

3. For global configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**") 
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add it to all controllers, as I have a lot of them. but I have configuraiton class and http.cors() but I added the bean I attached to my question. but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Yeah, so it's become easier if you give more information, and what spring boot config you are using or want to use. So I've just update the answer with global config option, hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

After deploying the war on tomcat, It didn't show the *.

so maybe it is only when start from intellij